# How to resolve ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when making HTTPS request to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My current stack is pretty simple:
Backend: Django 2.1.1, python 3.6 I am running it on elastic beanstalk with an application load balancer. I have port 80 listening for HTTP and port 443 listenin for HTTPS with my ssl certificate selected. I did not select an SSL policy as I have no idea what these do. As for the security groups, for both my port 80 and port 443 I have inbound sources set to 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0.

Frontend: React, mainly using axios to do requests (axios.get, axios.put, etc). I have this hosted on two s3 buckets, mainsite.com, where all my static files are, and www.mainsite.com, which redirects HTTP to that site. I also have 2 cloudfront distributions which redirect HTTP to HTTPs, using the same certificate as the one I used for my load balancer. I then created 2 record sets and set the alias to the cloud distribution. Previously when I tried to make HTTP requests, it would work. Now I have updated the urls to HTTPS urls but I end up with "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

This is my django.config in my .ebextensions folder:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: bonharvest/wsgi.py
container_commands:
  01_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you have not selected the SSL Policy. According to AWS:

> Elastic Load Balancing uses a Secure Socket Layer (SSL) negotiation
>   configuration, known as a security policy, to negotiate SSL
>   connections between a client and the load balancer. A security policy
>   is a combination of protocols and ciphers. The protocol establishes a
>   secure connection between a client and a server and ensures that all
>   data passed between the client and your load balancer is private.

It is recommended to use **ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08** policy for general purpose. So, modify your settings in the Elastic Beanstalk Configuration by selecting the SSL policy and try accessing your url. For more information on SSL policies, refer to this link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html

Comment: Ok it turns out I forgot I already had one selected (2015 one). Nonetheless, I changed it and still have the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT problem. Is there anything else I need to config?